# Infinite While True Loop in the Background (Python)

Tags: python, multithreading, background-process

basically, I have some code like this:

```
while True:
   number = int(len(oilrigs)) * 49
   number += money
   time.sleep(1)
```

In front of this I have a start up screen. However because of this while true loop, it blocks it from running the actual start up screen. Instead, it just displays this.

So how do you put the code in the background?

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: I meant to say, how do you put the code in the background?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try multithreading.

```
import threading

def background():
    while True:
        number = int(len(oilrigs)) * 49
        number += money
        time.sleep(1)

def foreground():
    # What you want to run in the foreground

b = threading.Thread(name='background', target=background)
f = threading.Thread(name='foreground', target=foreground)

b.start()
f.start()
```

Comment: Great response, however, what does the following mean?

    b = threading.Thread(name='background', target=background)

Comment: That means that you have two different threads running concurrently. This allows for processes to run in parallel. The `background` thread is running your loop, whereas the `foreground` thread is running whatever you want in the foreground.

Comment: Out of interest, what do 'background' and 'foreground' really mean in this context? Does the foreground thread have any sort of priority over the background because it's called after? Concurrency seems to suggest that they're completely independent of one another?

Comment: @TomGreenwood This was ~4 years ago so I don't fully remember, but I believe that I called `background` as such because it was running an infinite loop. There's no prioritization here or at least no attempt to imply there is prioritization.