# How can I run a while loop which edits a aiosqlite database but is not in a async function

Tags: python, asynchronous, async-await, nextcord, aiosqlite

```
if True:
    import shortcuts.startupload
    from shortcuts.startupload import *
    import threading
    import time

**def background():
    while True:
        if 1 == 1:
            if 1 == 1:
                gwtimes = await aiosqlite.connect('gwtimes.db')
                async with gwtimes.cursor() as gwcursor:
                    await gwcursor.execute("UPDATE gwtimes SET time=time+50")
                await gwtimes.commit()
                async with gwtimes.cursor() as gwcursor:
                    await gwcursor.execute("SELECT time FROM gwtimes")
                    number = await gwcursor.fetchone()
                print(number)**

def foreground():
    (other code) 

b = threading.Thread(name='background', target=background)
f = threading.Thread(name='foreground', target=foreground)

b.start()
f.start()


    
bot.run(hidden token)
```

Above is most of the whole thing

I need it to (in the background) add 50 to all values in the column every 1 second and then print the time so I can test its working, however I dont get how to use async and await with this as the error is saying:

````
    gwtimes = await aiosqlite.connect('gwtimes.db')
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: 'await' outside async function```
````

Comment: Did you mean to use `async def background():`?

Comment: I know there are unnecessary things such as if 1 == 1: but they make it easier later on if I want to add a check and I don't need to move the whole code later

Comment: umm, give me one second

Comment: This is where I got it from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38254172/infinite-while-true-loop-in-the-background-python

Comment: I would recommend reading up a tutorial on asyncio before just throwing async and await everywhere.